# Error in UseMethod("droplevels") in r

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm trying to impute my data using this R code..
but i can not get the problem

```
 data=as.matrix(as.data.frame(data))
 na.omit(data)

 library(FactoMineR)
 res.mca1 = MCA(data,quali.sup=c(1:50))

 class(data)
 library(missMDA)
 data <- droplevels(data)
 nb <- estim_ncpMCA(data,ncp.max=5) 
 tab.disj <- imputeMCA(data, ncp=4)$tab.disj

 res.mca <- MCA(data,tab.disj=tab.disj)
```

I get this Error :

```
 Error in UseMethod("droplevels") : 
 no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class     "c('matrix', 'character')"
```

Any help please ?

Comment: 1: What's `data`; 2) `droplevels` is meant to be used with `factor` variables, you are using `character`.

Comment: Yea it's the data class. Could be that it's the `matrix` class or if not the `character` class it's being applied to but either way it's for `factor` only

Comment: all my variables are categorical..What should i do ? how to correct the problem ?

Comment: @KarimaTouati; if you have any categorical / factor variables in your dataframe, when you use `as.matrix` it will convert all variables (including numeric variables) to character. character variables do not have levels, hence `droplevels` throws an error (example: `droplevels(letters[1:3])` ). The helppage of `?FactoMineR::MCA` suggests it takes a dataframe, so perhaps you do not need to convert your dataframe to a matrix. Then droplevels will likely work if your categroical variables are stored as factors in your dataframe.